# Why does IntelliJ IDEA prefer constants first in comparisons?

Tags: intellij-idea

IDEA suggests to flip comparisons like `(object.method() == CONSTANT)` to `(CONSTANT == object.method())` but it doesn't give a reason. Is the second way really better and if yes, why?

I know that the order matters for the short-circuiting operators `&&` and `||`, but for the other binary operators, the function has to be evaluated anyway. What am I missing here?

I use IntelliJ IDEA 2016 1.3.

Comment: If you accept the suggestion, it will suggest to flip it again. It's up to you to decide what you find the most readable. Otherwise, it doesn't matter.

Comment: You can also take a look at the [Yoda conditions wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions), which describes both the advantages (some present in the answers below as well) and the criticism

Comment: @JBNizet For `while (tree.children().length == 1)`, it will flip it once and then suggest to flip it back but accepting the flip back will not do anything.

Comment: @Morfic The Yoda conditions page fits perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Glad to help, may the source be with you...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't "prefer" constants first. There are two inspections, "Constant on the left side of comparison" and "Constant on the right side of comparison", both of which are disabled by default. If you see the code like `object.method() == CONSTANT` highlighted as a warning, then it was enabled in your project code style, and you should ask whoever configured your project style for their reasoning. Some code styles prefer to put constants on the left to ensure that, if someone accidentally uses `=` instead of `==`, the code will fail to compile because you can't assign to a constant.

There is also an intention action to flip any comparison operation. Intention actions are tools that can be applied to automate certain code editing operations. Their availability does not indicate any preference from IntelliJ IDEA's side; they're just tools for editing code.

Answer (score 2):

Many of the analysis checks are provided for development teams that have coding standards that for one reason or another prefer a certain order for operations.  They can be turned on or off according to the organization's policies, and the policies can even be distributed to developers to encourage uniformity.  Because of this, some of the analyses are contradictory, since some orgs will prefer one way and others the other way. It is up to the org in such cases to explain why one is better than the other.

As far as why it is this way by default, I can suggest two reasons, not having to do with the ordering of `==` operands, but because the order makes sense for `equals` and `assertEquals` comparisons and a coding standard might want the order to be the same for == comparisons.

First, it is often safer to put the constant first.  For example, the expression

```
if(CONSTANT.equals(foo)){...}
```

is safer than

```
if(foo.equals(CONSTANT)){...}
```

because the first one will not get a NPE if foo is null.

Second, it can simplify code.  For instance, the following are equivalent:

```
if(foo != null && foo.equals(CONSTANT)){...}

if(CONSTANT.equals(foo))
```

Another reason perhaps is that in some apis the "expected" value generally comes before the value being tested, as in junit's `assertEquals`, which will yield incorrect diagnostic information if the expected value does not come first.

A reason I have heard in the past is that it reads better when the expected value in a comparison comes first--you don't have to hunt for the value being checked for in an expression if it comes first.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely just a checkstyle preference. I have seen both variations preferred in different teams/projects. In practice, it is just a question of personal preference.

Find out which checkstyle implementation IntelliJ is configured to work with. It is not to your liking you can always download another one and use it instead.